# Google Drive API 403 Forbidden error if i upgrade to Gradle Plugin v3.5.0

Tags: android, google-drive-api, gradle-plugin

I recently updated the Gradle plugin from version `3.4.2` to `3.5.0`.
The code to access the list of Drive files has stopped working.
I get: `403 Forbidden  domain`": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
if I use `3.4.2` it works perfectly again.

```
// Login
signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
            .build();
GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(Backup.this, signInOptions);
startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
            handleSignInResult(resultData);
        }
        ...
    }
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
}

private void handleSignInResult(Intent result) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount) {
            // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
            GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(Backup.this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
            credential.setSelectedAccount(googleAccount.getAccount());
            Drive googleDriveService =
                    new Drive.Builder(
                            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                            new GsonFactory(),
                            credential)
                            .setApplicationName("MyAPP")
                            .build();

            mDriveServiceHelper = new BackupDriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);

            // get info
            mDriveServiceHelper.readFileInfo()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Bundle>() {
                    ...
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    ...
                });
            ...
        }
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        }
    });
}



public class BackupDriveServiceHelper {
    ...
    public Task<Bundle> readFileInfo() {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, new Callable<Bundle>() {
            @Override
            public Bundle call() throws Exception {
                // Retrieve the metadata as a File object.
                String pageToken = null;
                do {
                    FileList result = mDriveService.files().list()
                            .setSpaces("drive")
                            .setFields("files(id, name, size, modifiedTime, description)")
                            .setPageToken(pageToken)
                            .execute();     // <<<<< error 403
                    ...
                    pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
                } while (pageToken != null);
                ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what is causing this? I have the same problem after upgrading Gradle from 3.1.2 to 3.5.0. It could be related to this warning: "The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.0." ? The Android target and build versions are set to 27 - I had them at 28, but that did not solve the problem

Comment: The solution indicated here works:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131072620
Include the following in your proguard-rules.pro:

    -keepclassmembers class * {
       @ com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
    }

Answer (score 6):

I found that while targetting Android 8 (API27) I could get Google Drive to work with Gradle 3.5.0 if I added this to the project gradle.properties

```
android.enableD8=false
```

However, after targetting Android 9 (API 28) and replacing android.support.* with androidx.* I get this warning:

```
The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
```

and the problem returns. It seems to me the D8 DEX compiler is causing the problem, but it can no longer be disabled?

I have filed a bug report for D8
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140882055

Update: the solution suggested by Google does indeed work: after adding this to proguard-rules.pro Google Drive works with Gradle 5.4.1 and Plugin 3.5.0

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Such things should be printed at the very top of the google drive api documentation!

Comment: Nice! Worked for me. After hours of searching... Thanks